# Eigen dynamic vs fixed size and assertion error

Tags: c++, class, eigen

I am using several Eigen MatrixXd and VectorXd, but I am getting somewhat confused about what is Dynamic vs Fixed Size. According to Eigen documentation, the size of fixed structures is known at *compile time*. With every Matrix I use I define their size when I instantiate them, and do not change the size while the program is running.

More precisely, I am using a class with several MatrixXd and VectorXd members, with their size being defined on the constructor of the class. Does that mean they are dynamically allocated? Therefore I do not need any type of optimization to speed up the code, like the ones suggested on [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html), right?

The reason I am asking this is even though by Eigen's definition I am using dynamic-size structures, I've come across the following assertion error several times already, and the only plausible cause would be Cause no.1 on [the suggested documentation page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html).

```
[darwin-pi2] darwin-pi2: /usr/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:67: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double; int Size = 32400; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed
```

Comment: You missed the essential information: what are the matrix size?

Comment: It is passed on as an argument to the constructor, usually 10x10 or 15x15.